# BigQuery is creating a STRUCT of NULLs when a row has no matching LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, arrays, count, google-bigquery, left-join

I have table called `models`. I have another table called `labelled_data` that has `modelId` and `classId`.  For every row in `models`, I need to count how many times each `classId` occurs in `labelled_data`.

The following BigQuery result has column `class` that is an `ARRAY` of `STRUCT`s.

```
WITH labelled_data AS(
  SELECT
    modelId,
    classId,
    COUNT(*) as count 
  FROM `abc.xyz.labelled_data`
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)

SELECT
  m.id,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(ld.classId AS id, ld.count)
  ) AS class,
FROM `abc.xyz.models` m
LEFT JOIN labelled_data AS ld ON ld.modelId = m.id
GROUP BY 1
```

The problem is that if there is no matching `LEFT JOIN` between `models` and `labelled_data`, `class` contains a single `STRUCT` element whose elements are `NULL`.

Here what most rows look like in JSON format:

```
{
    "id": "43A4BBA0-7D3D-466B-B893-CE1397223EB6",
    "class": [
      {
        "id": "F0CD7177-2608-4DA3-90F4-69DF435E3C3B",
        "count": "42"
      },
      {
        "id": "25FB2670-FBA8-4961-B4BC-535776FDE6D3",
        "count": "40"
      }
    ]
}
```

Here is a problematic row:

```
{
    "id": "428E6D3C-98A3-4B9E-BB50-DCD589C6E321",
    "class": [
      {
        "id": null,
        "count": null
      }
    ]
}
```

I would like the desired result to be:

```
{
    "id": "428E6D3C-98A3-4B9E-BB50-DCD589C6E321",
    "class": null
}
```

Note that I cannot exclude that row from the results. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `case` expression that ensures that there is at least one matching row:

```
WITH (...)
SELECT
    m.id,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(ld.modelid) > 0
        THEN ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(ld.classId AS id, ld.count)) 
    END AS class,
FROM `abc.xyz.models` m
LEFT JOIN labelled_data AS ld ON ld.modelId = m.id
GROUP BY 1
```